# increment or decrement ts_nodash seconds in dag

Tags: python, datetime, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Is there a way to increment or decrement seconds in {{ts_nodash}} in airflow dag?
because of the same datetime obtained by {{ts_nodash}} my output is getting overwritten. is there a way to increment {{ts_nodash}} with 1-2 secs
like we can do for days in {{ ds }} -

```
airflow.macros.ds_add(ds, days) 

ds_add('2015-01-01', 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two way to go about this.

1. Create your own macro like [ds_add](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.0/airflow/macros/__init__.py#L29-L46) and put it in your [plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html).
2. Use python code in Jinja templating.

Option 2 is the easiest and most straight forward.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="trigger_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 3, 10),
    catchup=True,
    schedule_interval='@once',
)

with dag:
    op = PythonOperator(
        task_id='a',
        python_callable=lambda x, y: print(x, y),
        op_args=[
            '{{ ts_nodash }}',
            '{{ execution_date.subtract(seconds=2).strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")  }}',
        ],
    )
```

The way `ts_nodash` is obtained is shown in [how the context is built](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.0/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1527). We are essentially building on the datetime object that would be formatted to string.

Here is the rendered template view for the task.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the pendulum date macros instead of the date strings. You can manipulate the dates and turn it back to a string

```
import pendulum
....
execution_date.subtract(seconds=2).to_datetime_string()
```

Comment: can I save it to a variable - exe_datetime = execution_date.subtract(seconds=2).to_datetime_string() and use ''exe_datetime'' @Andrew Cheng